# Have a basic GUI Code created in Flutter, can't get it to run on VS Code. Need screenshots of output

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, takesscreenshot

I can't seem to get this code to run using VS Code, and I need the results of the emulator (mobile app on an iPhone), is anyone able to run it and get the output? (Can you please post screenshots of it?)

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Product Catalog Search'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter search keywords',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed:(){
                //TODO: Implement search functionality
              },
              child: Text('Search'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('No matching products'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

What problem you are facing?
I got no problem executing it.

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]

run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` in the vs code terminal.

Comment: When I try running the code, I keep getting an error saying the 'Target of URI doesn't exist' and that the name 'MyApp' isn't a class. It also says in the terminal that the 'dart' command isn't found. I just installed flutter on my MacBook and I'm not sure what's going on :/

Comment: Thank you by the way for the help, it really means a lot to at least knowing my code works!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After compiling your code here is the result

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it! It's good to know that at least knowing my code works!

Comment: Here is the code I compiled => https://codeshare.io/qPZR7Z